# Finding attributes from selective elements using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XMl:

```
<bookstore specialty="novel">
    <book style="autobiography">
        <title>Seven Years in Trenton</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Joe</first-name>
            <last-name>Bob</last-name>
        </author>
        <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
        <price>12</price>
    </book>
    <book style="textbook">
        <title>History of Trenton</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Mary</first-name>
            <last-name>Bob</last-name>
        </author>
        <price type="regular">55</price>
        <price type="sale">45</price>
    </book>
    <magazine style="glossy" frequency="monthly">
        <title>Tracking Trenton</title>
        <price>2.50</price>
        <subscription price="24" per="year"/>
    </magazine>
    <Textbook style="Science" id="myfave">
        <title>Trenton Today, Trenton Tomorrow</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Toni</first-name>
            <last-name>Bob</last-name>
            <degree from="Trenton U">B.A.</degree>
            <degree from="Harvard">Ph.D.</degree>
            <award>Pulitzer</award>
        </author>
        <price intl="canada" exchange="0.7">6.50</price>
        <excerpt>
            It was a dark and stormy night.But then all nights in Trenton seem dark and stormy to someone who has gone through what can only be defined as Trenton misery
        </excerpt>
    </Textbook>
</bookstore>
```

Using XPath I need to find all the style attributes of element type Book and Magazine but NOT Textbook. I am running into this problem as I cant figure out how to separate between the 3 elements as they are all in same level. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard `*` to select all child element of `bookstore`.

Use a filter `[not(name()='Textbook')]` to distinguish those elements you're interested in.

Finally:

```
/bookstore/*[not(name()='Textbook')]/@style
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be:

```
/bookstore/*[name()='book' or name()='magazine']/@style
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `self::` instead of `name()`...

```
/bookstore/*[not(self::Textbook)]/@style
```

I'd do the same if I was checking for `magazine` or `book` too...

```
/bookstore/*[self::magazine or self::book]/@style
```

You could also use a sequence with `name()` (XPath 2.0)...

```
/bookstore/*[name()=('magazine','book')]/@style
```